# Django form fields not showing up on webpage

Tags: django, django-forms

I am doing a "Contact Us" section on my site. When I goto the contact section on my webpage it displays like:  [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfKTs.png)

I'm not sure if its related to my url because the contact section of the page shows up like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/#contact-section` ?

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms 

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponse

from contact.forms import ContactForm

def index_view(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})

def post_view(request):
    return render(request, 'single.html', {})

def contact_us(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Send email goes here
            return HttpResponse("Thanks for contacting, We will be in touch soon!")
    else: 
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

**Template**

```
<div class="row no-gutters block-9">
          <div class="col-md-6 order-md-last d-flex">
            <form method="POST" action="." class="bg-light p-4 p-md-5 contact-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                {% csrf_token %}
                  {{ form.as_p }}         
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5">
              </div>
            </form>
           </div>
```

Comment: are you using the dev server or did you restart your server after changing your files.

Comment: I am using the dev server, I restarted it a few times and even tried the 'collectstatic' method.

Comment: You have the same template for `index_view()` and `contact_us()`. If you are calling index_view() when opening `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` url, then form cannot be rendered since form is not in the context of that view.

Comment: Ahhh I see! is it possible to call a section of a view/template? When I click the link in the Navbar It scrolls to the contact section but still on the index.html page just changes to the  #contact-section. Is it possible to add the logic from the contact_us to index view?  Thank you for your response!

Comment: Sure, you can move the code/logic from contact_us to index_view.

Comment: Can you add your URL file here?